# Using ApkLib projects on Eclipse doesn't show errors when they should be shown

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors, maven-plugin

We have created some ApkLib projects .

the projects of the app are:

- ApkLib project 1
- ApkLib project 2 , uses ApkLib project 1
- The main project (of the app) uses both of the ApkLib projects

Using Maven, when everything seems fine, it compiles and all, but during editing, I don't see any warnings and errors that are about Android/Java on the errors/warnings window (called "Problems" View, shown by using the combination ALT+SHIFT+Q and then X).

for example when I delete a function that other classes call, it doesn't write anything on the warnings window.

however, when I go to the classes that call the deleted function, I can see the errors in the editor itself (marked with red), yet again, in the warnings window there isn't a single warning/error written there related to this issue.

Another example is that when a class implements an interface, and I delete the functions of the interface inside the class, I immediately see the error on the editor itself, but not on the errors/warnings window.

This means that Eclipse almost doesn't help at all with errors for the ApkLib projects, and instead of using eclipse's built in windows , I can only see the errors inside the console, when compiling using Maven (which takes a very long time).

What can I do to fix it?

the only errors I always get are the next ones (i've replaced the paths and project names with XXX ) , one for each of the projects:

> Cannot parse lifecycle mapping metadata for maven project MavenProject: XXX @ XXX\pom.xml Cause: Unrecognised tag: 'action' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n        ... @26:17)  pom.xml /XXX    line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

seems like there wasn't a java build in the ".project" file.

[**this link**](http://solveme.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/eclipse-project-missing-default-java-builder/) has helped me . i've added the next things into the ".project" file:

```
<buildSpec>
<buildCommand>
<name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
<arguments>
</arguments>
</buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
<nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```